# how can i go to a routed page in quasar?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm trying to make this happen when i click the

example:

> div

i want it to go to specific page

this example route

```
{ path: 'petInformation', component: () => import('src/pages/petInformation.vue') },
```

in quasar component if there is `to` in its api. routing is good.

> `example: <q-btn to="petInformation"/>`

however, is it possible to make an html element like div when click go to a specific page in quasasr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quasar uses [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) underneath for page routing.

Here's an example of how to use Vue Routers Programmatic Navigation to do what you're trying to accomplish.

```
<div @click="$router.push('petInformation/')">Click Me</div>
```

This causes a router push on the div's click.

Comment: thanks bro, have not try it yet. because i make other solution. in case your answer works thanks for your answer